# how to determine if a range was selected in Excel VBA - Multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform in Excel 2012 whereby when the user double clicks on a specific range of cells the userform pops up.

This can be done by running the following vba code in the specific pages module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
            'condition to run when not clicked in range
         Cancel = True
            'condition to run if cell in range was clicked
         userform1.show
    End If
End Sub
```

This works perfectly.

The only problem is, since you are checking if not condition, I am unable to run many IF conditions to enable the functionality that will display a range of forms when the user clicks on different sections of the worksheet

Do you know how to enable an if statement that will check if different ranges are clicked, and for each range, show a different userform?

thanks

Comment: I think you MIGHT find your answer below.

Comment: @BernardSaucier: Is that comment for me? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Nah, it was for OP; he/she has PLENTY of answers to choose from :p I just hope we didn't misunderstand the question, or the answer might NOT be below... hehe.

Comment: @SiddharthRout for some reason ElseIF is not working on 2012... but thanks, invistigating answers now..

Comment: @BernardSaucier: Mine, user2140261's and your answer is the same... :)

Comment: @Hightower: Are you sure enableevents = true?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Pretty much what I meant :p

Comment: @Hightower: What do you mean `ElseIf` is not working? The structure is not recognized? Or not behaving correctly?

Comment: It was not recognising the ElseIf Construct???

Comment: Try splitting them apart : `Else` on one line and then `If` on the next.

Comment: Are you sure you respected the format : `If  condition  Then ` [...] `ElseIf  condition  Then` [...] `End If`

Comment: yes. was definitely somewhere.. i did not respect the correct format, since the below solutions all work for me.. Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
            'condition to run when not clicked in range
         Cancel = True
            'condition to run if cell in range was clicked
         userform1.show
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        'condition to run when not clicked in range
     Cancel = True
        'condition to run if cell in range was clicked
     userform2.show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this solution, since each condition specifically raises a cancel event, thereby forcing excel to return the beforeDoubleClick event to a cancel state -- if the cancel is not called, Excel double click functions will be affected in other cells.. (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple ranges in your `Intersect` arguments and then test for `Column` to see which range was clicked. An example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10, C1:C10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then
            useform1.show //Show userform1 if A1:A10 clicked
        ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
            useform2.show //Show userform2 if C1:C10 clicked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in comments why not an `ElseIf`?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then

    '
    '`~> And So on
    '
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much needs to be modified in your code to achieve what you want to.

Try this!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Column A"

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Column B"

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C10")) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Column C"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution(s) are all correct as per the question, however, based on the fact that the userdialog is actually being called for a particular column header, I decided that a select case would work better for me (where the extension of the worksheet will not affect the forms which are shown)

hence the code below looks for the particular column name (where the column is the first record on the row) and shows the form based on that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Check the columName to determine which Form to Show
  Select Case Cells(1, Target.Column)
      Case "Column1"
         UserForm1.Show
      Case "Column2"
        UserForm2.Show
      Case Else
        Cancel = True
  End Select
End Sub
```